# Deserializing Map from Json, using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Lets say your Json consist of a bunch of freeform pairs

```
"config": {
    "k1": "abc",
    "k2": "xyz"
},
```

Rules

- I don't know how many keys i'll have
- All values will be Strings
- I'd like for map to be addressable by a key

Where some of the values are Strings and others are Numbers. I was thinking that HashMap

```
public class Outer {

    private Config config = new Config();

    public Config getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }


    public class Config {
        private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        public Map<String, String> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }
    }
}
```

When using testing this, i see that `getConfig()` returns a non-null value. But when i get to `getMap()` i get `null`

Please help me understand what am i missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use just:

```
public class Outer {

    private Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
    public void setConfig(Map<String, String> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

---

In the class model you wrote, you are *describing* a JSON like this:

```
"config": {
    "map": {
        "k1": "abc",
        "k2": "xyz"
    }
},
```

but as you can see, that's not what you want...

You have to realize that the field `config` in your JSON is not an object that contains a field called `map` that represents a `Map`... but the field `config` **represents itself a `Map`**!